# Combining getting value from SharedPrefs and network with RxJava

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

What would be the best way to combine those operations with RxJava:

1. Get auth token from shared prefs
2. If it doesn't exist or not valid, get it from the server.
3. Perform a request with the valid one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have two observables one that returns `AuthToken` from shared prefs and another that returns `AuthToken` from the server:

```
Observable<AuthToken> authTokenFromPrefs = ...;
Observable<AuthToken> authTokenFromServer = ...;
```

Then construct an observable from the above two that uses the `AuthToken` and returns the results of a service call:

```
Observable<T> results = 
  authTokenFromPrefs
    .filter(AuthToken::isValid)
    .switchIfEmpty(authTokenFromServer)
    .flatMap(authToken -> callService(authToken));
```

Comment: And then the actual call should be done with a 'flatMap'? Turning the auth observable to a call observable, right?

Comment: Yeah sure you could do that. I've update the answer with possible usage.

Comment: @DaveMoten: `switchIfEmpty` is marked as `@Experimental`. Do you suggest to use it?

Comment: Yep use it. It'll stick around I'd say.